# Saving an array of structs to userDefaults

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I have the user take a picture of an item of clothing, then give it a tag describing what type it is (pants, shirt, shoes, etc). I then take this info and save it into a struct Item. After that, I put the recently made Item into an array of Items. I'm struggling with how to save this array of Items to UserDefaults so I can load back when the app is closed.

I've tried adding Codable to my struct but that just brought up more issues. I wanted to update the UserDefaults every time the user adds a new item to the array. I plan to do it in `saveItemButton` function (shown below).

```
var itemsArray: [Item] = []

//.pants, .shirt, .shoes, .hat, .extra, .jacket
var itemType: clothingType? = nil

@IBAction func saveItemButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if(itemType != nil && imageView.image != nil){
        saveImage(imageName: ("item" + "\(itemsArray.count)"))
        let item = Item(itemType: itemType!, itemName: ("item" + "\(itemsArray.count)"))


        itemsArray.append(item)

        //let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        //defaults.set(itemsArray, forKey: "SavedItemArray")
    }
}
```

Here is my struct in a separate swift file:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


struct Item{
    var itemType: clothingType
    var itemName: String
    //var itemImage: UIImage?
}

enum clothingType{
    case pants
    case shirt
    case jacket
    case shoes
    case hat
    case extra
}
```

And here is where I would load the itemArray from UserDefaults:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    //        let array = defaults.array(forKey: "SavedItemArray")  as? [Item] ?? [Item]()
    //        itemsArray = array
}
```

Looking to be able to save and load an array of Item to UserDefaults.

Comment: Do not store your app data in UserDefaults. Making your data codable and persisting to a plist is a better option.

Comment: @rmaddy Why is it better? Is this a moral judgment or is there a technical issue?

Comment: UserDefaults is meant for storing little bits of information such as settings and preferences. It is not meant for storing large amounts of data.

Comment: it is Swift naming convention to name your enumerations starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: @rmaddy UserDefaults _is_ a plist. What difference does it make whether we read/write from it or from a file? Where are you getting this "little bits" requirement?

Comment: @matt Yes, I know `UserDefaults` is a plist itself but that's an implementation detail. `UserDefaults` is meant for storing simple key-value pairs. Real app data should be stored in its own place whether it's a plist file or full blown database. There are countless posts and comments on SO that recommend not storing app data in UserDefaults.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm using UserDefaults to store quite a lot of data. If this is technically bad I want to know about it. Repeating the same canard, or saying that it is frequently repeated, doesn't help me. Can you give me a _reason_ rather than a religious conviction?

Comment: @matt UserDefaults is loaded into memory. It's persisted at unknown intervals. It provides extra layers in the form of domains. It was never meant to be a persistent store for lots of app data. App data should use its own persistence store. It should be wrapped by it's own class that controls what is stored and loaded. When you get to the point of having thousands of records in your data, you don't want that all in memory at once. UserDefaults is not a database. It's essentially an in-memory dictionary.

Comment: @rmaddy "UserDefaults is loaded into memory" I don't know that. Obviously if I fetch something from UserDefaults it needs to be loaded, but I don't know if it is released again. And if I have a big value in UserDefaults, reading that same big value from a plist file is no better. Now, if you want to draw the distinction between UserDefaults and a real _database_, fine. But that isn't what you said: you suggested that an `[Item]` would be better off stored as a plist file.

Comment: UserDefaults is documented as being in memory by Apple:
"
UserDefaults caches the information to avoid having to open the user’s defaults database each time you need a default value. When you set a default value, it’s changed synchronously within your process, and asynchronously to persistent storage and other processes.
"
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

This also happens on app startup. Like has been said, it's better to use a plist you control the lifecycle of if you have a large amount of data. Otherwise app start will get worse and worse.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Like this:

```
struct Item : Codable {
    var itemType: clothingType
    var itemName: String
}

enum clothingType : String, Codable {
    case pants
    case shirt
    case jacket
    case shoes
    case hat
    case extra
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let data = defaults.data(forKey: "SavedItemArray") {
            let array = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data)
        }
    }
}
```

Of course I suppose now you're wondering how we got the data into user defaults in the first place. Like this:

```
    let array : [Item] = // whatever
    if let data = try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(array) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "SavedItemArray")
    }
```

Comment: This solved my issue! Responding to @rmaddy and your debate, I have also heard not to use UserDefaults, but this is for a Mobile App Development class and we've yet to learn how to save persistent data in any other way so I didn't want to do something I hadn't learned. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @rmaddy comment says

> Saving those kind of data into the `UserDefault` is not recommended

however technically let's say you're going to save those however you like, `UserDefault` don't accept this type of structure, what you need to do is 
converting this array to type `Data` saving it into the `UserDefault` then fetch it as `Data` then cast it back to it's original form, but again this is not recommended.

Read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) .

Also hitting search on this

> [what is user defaults for swift](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1440&bih=752&ei=ATy_XJvKEIfcwAKiq5zgDw&q=what%20is%20user%20defaults%20for%20%20swift%3F&oq=what%20is%20user%20defaults%20for%20%20swift%3F&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1394.1965..2107...0.0..0.113.659.0j6......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j33i10.OfbNy9l7w-g) ?

Will give you the answer of this

> The user defaults is a `.plist` file in your app's package and you can use it to set and get **simple pieces of data**. It's structure is very similar to that of a dictionary and the user defaults are often regarded as a key-value store .